# Ember.js - route ignores query params passed in as hashes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am building a route meant to take in several query params, one of which is a Hash:

```
http://www.test.com/foo/bar?first_name=Johnny&hashparam[][foo]=bar
```

Controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ["first_name", "hashparam"]
});
```

Route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    console.log(params.first_name);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params.hashparam));
  }
});
```

For the above example request, "Johnny" is successfully logged to the console, but the second logs "undefined". I debugged into the code and see that `params` includes a key for `hashparam` but its value is `undefined`. I can't figure out why because from what I can tell, the request above is using the correct format to pass in a hash key and value. I also added a `beforeModel` hook to my route so I can investigate the incoming `Transition` and I see that `queryParams` includes a key named `hashparam[][foo]` with value `'bar'`.

What's wrong here? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing a key of `hashparam`, you are providing a key of `hashparam[][foo]`.

Comment: Normally passing in a query parameter of `hashparam[][foo]` would result in a query param that is itself a hash with a key of `foo` and value `"bar"`. What's different here?

Comment: What do you mean 'normally'?  What parser are you using?

Comment: Ok, I see what you're getting at. I was using rails to come up with the query string, and I think only rails supports that format. That explains why ember isn't behaving the same way.

Comment: You may want to create an issue in the ember project on github or ember-parachute on github.  You may get some support for that sort of feature, or someone may have a workaround.  Rails has often been the basis for certain implementations of parts of ember so it's not beyond possibility that they would want to add support for this.

Comment: That's a fantastic suggestion, thank you! I'll do that.